# Get anchor value from absolute url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this jQuery selector:

```
$("a[href*='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(#valueinhere)
});
```

to select links that link to an anchor

My links are absolute and relative so they can look like `http://www.myweb.com/test#anchor` or like `test#anchor` or like `#anchor`

How to get the string `#anchor` from all links above? Is there any regex or something like that?

(I can't use `window.location.hash` because of `e.preventDefault()` that is necessary)

Comment: You want to get the `hash` from the `href` of the `a` elements, or from the browser's address bar/location?

Comment: @David did you read the post? Clearly he wants the hash from the `a` tag

Comment: So why is he even considering `window.location.hash`? And yes; I did read the question, before asking my own question.

Comment: I just added `window.location.hash` info because sometimes there are some people who reply in the way I don't need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you get the `hash` from the anchor element?

```
this.hash
```

It is independent of whether you're preventing the default behavior of the click event.

```
$("a[href*='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.hash);
});
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UXeBN/).

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a[href*='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( this.href.split("#")[1] )
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(this.href.split("#")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `indexOf` in `String`

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');                    
    e.preventDefault();
    var newUrl = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));
    alert(newUrl);
});
```

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/8SdW2/1/